# Store Small Number of NSMutableArrays (with plist)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist

I need store just 10 arrays in my app, which I can change from time to time. What would the best way to do this be?

I have been looking into writing to a plist, is this a good idea?

Each of the 10 arrays will have 10 objects (just strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an NSDictionary (or rather the mutable version in your case) and populate it with your arrays. Then you could write them to disk with

```
writeToFile:atomically:
```

At start you could check whether your path is valid (meaning your dict exists) and assign it to your iVar in code for example with

```
initWithContentsOfFile:
```

The advantage is that the underlying representation is a plist for the NSDictionary (or NSMutableDictionary). So you are good to go here as well and as your objects within the arrays conform to `NSCoding` they all know how to encode them for writing to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Using a plist file is a fine way to go as long as you don't need to interoperate with a non-Objective-C codebase (e.g. share with a Windows app, send the data to a server, etc.)